# TSQL LEN(Substring) returning wrong number

Tags: t-sql, substring, string-length

I have this bit of code reading in a fixed width file into a table with one column 'A' that's created as varchar(300) then reading that table as...

`LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARBINARY,SUBSTRING(A,101,4))))`
and in most cases it returns a 4 digit year.  I am coming across an error where I have a typo in the file that I received where the year is '20' so

`LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARBINARY,SUBSTRING(A,101,4))))`
returns a 20 and I wanted to put in the where statement a filter that says that

`LEN( LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARBINARY,SUBSTRING(A,101,4)))) ) = 4`

the problem is when I run 

`LEN( LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARBINARY,SUBSTRING(A,101,4)))) )`
in the select statement the '20' shows up as having a 4 LEN.  What is this thing doing?
I'm not sure exactly why the VARBINARY is there, I think it has something to do with when the value from the mainframe is set as integer and NULL it comes across as '.' and that cleans it up.  Regardless I still get this issue when I remove the CONVERT(VARBINARY.

Comment: What's the conversion to VARBINARY for?  Also, what comes after the date (i,e, is it the last data in the row; if not you're picking up `20` followed by the first 2 characters of whatever's next).

Comment: Sometimes there's a "." instead of a number and the conversion, ltrim and rtrim help clean it up.
Even if I do DATALENGTH(SUBSTRING(A,101,4)) I still get 4

Comment: Respond IN the question and for the 3rd time whey the cast to VARBINARY?  Put A in a variable and reproduce the the problem.

Comment: So you added information of absolutely not value.  Post data IN the question to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) Returns the number of characters, rather than the number of bytes, of the given string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

[DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) Returns the number of bytes used to represent any expression. DATALENGTH is especially useful with varchar, varbinary, text, image, nvarchar, and ntext data types because these data types can store variable-length data. The DATALENGTH of NULL is NULL.

**EDIT**

I think I got it. Many times you mention about ".". In my opinion you have float value which is implicitly converted to varchar. Check below.

```
SELECT LEN(t.val), t.val
FROM  (SELECT 20.0) AS t(val)
```

Comment: <code>DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARBINARY,SUBSTRING(A,101,4)))))</code><br/>Still returns a 4

Comment: Please provide sample of A and its type. Probably new line characters, which are not trimmed when converted to varbinary.

Comment: It usually looks like 20150820 but in this case it's just the number 20 so I use a bunch of substrings to concat the digits into a date format.  In this case I'm trying to find when the year is not exactly 4 digits then don't pull in the record.

Comment: I understand but paste data which cause it after substring from source. `LEN( LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARBINARY, **your_data_and_type**  )))) )`. You can check it also for non-printable characters, BOM and so on.

Comment: You can also change to `LEN(CONVERT( VARBINARY,(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(A,101,4)))) )` but I still don't understand why  casting to VARBINARY.

Comment: Even when I get rid of the convert `LEN((LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(A,101,4))) ))` I still get a 4.  This data is from a flat file that I pull into one column in a temp table that is varchar(300) and then use substrings to pull the data and insert it into the permanent table (if that helps)

Comment: `DECLARE @sample NVARCHAR(10) = SUBSTRING(A,101,4)` and then we can talk about it.

Comment: This code `DECLARE @sample NVARCHAR(10), @samplelen int, @sampledl int 

select @sample = SUBSTRING(A,101,4) 
  , @samplelen = LEN(SUBSTRING(A,101,4))
  , @sampledl = DATALENGTH(SUBSTRING(A,101,4))
from #tblthf A 
where SUBSTRING(A,1,6) = 'HWGMGM'

print @sample
print @samplelen
print @sampledl` prints out these values `20` `4` `4`

Comment: Ok, then `SELECT (SUBSTRING(A,101,4)`, copy entire cell, paste to notepad++, show all characters( in options) and check what is there.

Comment: I used this code `select SUBSTRING(A,101,4)
from #tblthf A 
where SUBSTRING(A,1,6) = 'HWGMGM'`
- went into notepad ++
- opened a new document
- went to view/show symbol/show all characters
- copied the results from the grid in SQL MS to the new document and all it shows is a 20

Comment: Last attempt: try to reproduce your case in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share link here.

Comment: When I do this `CAST(SUBSTRING(A,101,4) AS INT)` I get this error if that means anything `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20..' to data type int.`

Comment: So you have '20..' not '20'.  '20..' is 4 characters.

Comment: Right but it only shows up that way in the error!  It doesn't show that way in the output, print or anything else!

Comment: It doesn't show unless you explicitly try to cast to INT. When doing your original query float is internally casted to varchar.

Comment: But when I do this in the where statement `SUBSTRING(A,101,4) <> '20..'` I still get the record.